# Project-wide formatting options for `dart format`

Tags: flutter, dart, formatting, static-analysis, code-formatting

I want to use `dart format` to format dart code, but my team uses custom format rules – such as line length of 120 characters and a few other things. Currently, code is formatted using settings in the IDE, but this is not ideal because it's not consistent across the team.

I know `analysis_options.yaml` can be used to configure static analysis, but I can't find a way to configure `dart format` to use the same rules.

Is there a way to configure `dart format` to use custom formatting rules?

---

Apparently, you can set line length by adding arguments `dart format --line-length 240 .`

I suppose the question is: What other options exist?

Comment: No https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-configure-it

Comment: @RichardHeap OP is asking for changing the line-length (which *is* configurable) project-wide (regardless of the individual developer's IDE settings).  However, I don't think that's possible either.

Comment: Looks like there are actually command line args that work `dart format --line-length 240 .` I have not found documentation on what options are available.

Comment: I agree - I can't point you to the existing discussion without it automatically closing it. See also https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues/833

Comment: There appear to be a few intentionally hidden options for `dart format` including line-length and indentation.

https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/blob/8c8caed8f89772d7fe336bb56a5e824782eb6cf2/lib/src/cli/options.dart#L88